# Kango Extension Cross Domain Request

Tags: ajax, response

I'm new to working with Kango and have setup a basic extension already. This is basically a conversion from an existing extension and I like everything so far. However, the docs feel a little light when it comes to doing an AJAX call cross-domain.

This is my existing code that worked 100% in the other extension framework:

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,                
    success:function(data){
       alert("success!")
    }
});
```

I'm seeing a 200 OK response, but the response itself is empty and I never see the alert.

I'm guessing this comes down to the need to use Kango api? I've tried all of their documentation samples and nothing seems to be working. The above is inside a content script, if that matters. I'm just trying to pull a file and read the contents, but this seems like more difficult than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to perform a cross domain request from a content script, you should use [kango.xhr.send](http://kangoextensions.com/docs/api-reference/kango-xhr.html#kango-xhr-send):

```
kango.xhr.send({url: 'http://example.com/'}, function(data) {
    if (data.status == 200 && data.response) {
        kango.console.log(data.response);
    }
    else {
        kango.console.log('something went wrong');
    }
});
```